# RGBDSLAM error: math_groups/se3quat.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am still having a problem with running RGBDSLAM on ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte.

I know what my problem is but I cannot resolve it. heres what I did.

I initially downloaded g2o into my workspace /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/trunk/. using the command svn co:  https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk. However I was getting some errors.

I then removed this file into the rubbish bin and followed the instructions given by this link: http://answers.ros.org/question/50585/rgbdslam-error-in-fuerte-and-electric/. I re-downloaded the g2o into home (/home/samme/trunk) by running this command:

svn co  https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk/

However, when I rosmake, I get this error :

/home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/edge.h:22:72: fatal error: /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/trunk/g2o/math_groups/se3quat.h: No such file or directory

The problem is that there is a conflict from my previous svn download. It is still trying to access that file (/home/samme/fuerte_workspace/trunk/g2o/) although I removed it to the rubbish bin.

Any ideas of how to resolve this conflict?

Thanks and best regards,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50750/rgbdslam-error:-math_groups/se3quat.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [746666288](https://answers.ros.org/users/4461/746666288/) on 2013-11-04**:
hi   I am new to rgbdslam  .my systerm is ubuntu11.10 64bit  electric  .when i type command"rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam"  error occured:致命错误： g2o/math_groups/se3quat.h：没有那个文件或目录  it like your error.so  i want to know how did you solve your problem.thanks

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-12-08**:
hello, I encountered a similar problem with you.when i type command"rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam". i get the error occured:g2o/math_groups/se3quat.h No such file or directory , Can you tell me how to solve this problem？ thanks a lot

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-12-08**:
It was a really long time so I do not remember the details. However I remember that there was a problem with g2o therefore I uninstalled the ROS g2o package and installing a general g2o. However I do not think this is a good solution and I am sure others have solved this problem in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realized I had previously played with the #include in some of the files. I restored it to the default settings. Now I am receiving a different error:

opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/core/hyper_graph.h:59:22: error: redefinition of ‘class g2o::HyperGraph’
/home/samme/trunk/g2o/include/g2o/core/hyper_graph.h:46:9: error: previous definition of ‘class g2o::HyperGraph’

It seems that there is a conflict between the g2o that I installed and the one in  ros-fuerte. Does anyone know how to uninstall the g2o that is already included in ROS?

Thanks,

Khalid

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) on 2012-12-22**:
Try uninstalling libg2o, if you have it installed, from the ubuntu software center. Remember to use `rosmake --pre-clean rgbdslam` so that you don't have files from the previous make interfering.